# Is it possible to have a 3G and bluetooth on a raspberry pi?

Tags: peripherals

Sorry for this question but I'm new on Raspberry PI.

I'm trying to develop a prototype that will need to connect to bluetooth devices, like smartphones, and have an Internet connection. Because I don't know if Rapsberry PI will always have WIFI connection, I thought to use a 3G module.

And probably, it will also need a camera, but I know there are camera's modules.

Is it possible to have a Raspberry PI with bluetooth, 3G and WIFI or ethernet connection?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can make it as you want. You can use a bluetooth Dongle on Raspberry Pi, and also make it as you want for that you must read the bluez stack to perform some modifications regarding making your own PAN (Personal area network).

There is one [good tutorial](http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x232.html) also to understand Bluetooth.

May it help you.